# How Delay mechanism works in embedded EFM32

Tags: c, arm, embedded, cortex-m

I cant see how the following code dmaking a delay?
We have SysTick iterrupt which i dont know what it means.
What is the meaning of SysTick_Config(CMU_ClockFreqGet(cmuClock_CORE)?
Thanks.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "em_device.h"
#include "em_chip.h"
#include "em_cmu.h"
#include "em_emu.h"
#include "bsp.h"
#include "bsp_trace.h"

void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
  msTicks++;       /* increment counter necessary in Delay()*/
}

void Delay(uint32_t dlyTicks)
{
  uint32_t curTicks;

  curTicks = msTicks;
  while ((msTicks - curTicks) < dlyTicks) ;
}

int main(void)
{
  /* Chip errata */
  CHIP_Init();
CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_GPIO,true);
/* Setup SysTick Timer for 1 msec interrupts  */
  if (SysTick_Config(CMU_ClockFreqGet(cmuClock_CORE) / 1000)) {
    while (1) ;
 }


}
```

Comment: Does the comment and the function name not make it clear?  Nothing in this code calls `Delay()` so it is unclear what you are asking.  The code does nothing useful just sitting in a do-nothing loop while `msTicks` is uselessly incremented every 1ms.  If you were to call `Delay`, it loops until `msTicks` is incremented through `dlyTicks` counts.

Comment: The variable `msTicks` is not declared so the code won't compile. Whether or not it is declared as signed and/or `volatile` and/or `_Atomic` matters. Post the relevant code not just fragments with missing declarations.

Comment: And why do you have a comment saying "Chip errata"? That's something which should cause all manner of bells and whistles to go off in the programmer's brain. What errata? What part of the code is the work-around?

Comment: Why would you use an interrupt/exception here?  if you are going to poll just poll the systick timer rollovers directly and/or sample the current value register and subtract until the time is exceeded, depending on the size of the delay you want.

Comment: EFM32s as shown on the website are built around cortex-m0+, m3 and m4s at this time.  All can have a systick timer and this code makes even less sense if the core doesnt.  The cortex-m0+ is armv6-m based and the other two are armv7-m based, either document will work as the systick timer is the same.  so go to arms website find the architectural reference manual for the armv6-m or armv7-m architecture and look at the systick timer.  how it works and how these functions relate then become quite clear it is an extremely simple peripheral.

Answer (score 1):

The EFM32 is an ARM Cortex-M based device which has a hardware timer/counter called SYSTICK.  SYSTICK increments at a rate related to the core clock frequency of the processor, in this case that frequency in counts-per-second is returned by `CMU_ClockFreqGet(cmuClock_CORE)`.

The reload value of SYSTICK can be set, here that is done by `SysTick_Config()`.  When the count reaches zero an interrupt is generated and the counter is reloaded.  Here by setting the count to the SYSTICK frequency divided by 1000, you will get an interrupt every one millisecond.

An interrupt causes an associated handler to be called asynchronously to the normal code flow (the while loop in main in this case).  So here `SysTick_Handler()` is called every 1 ms, incrementing `msTicks` (a count of elapsed milliseconds).

The `Delay()` function polls `msTicks` until `dlyTicks` have elapsed.  `curTicks` is a snapshot of the value of `msTicks` at the start of the delay, the expression `(msTicks - curTicks) < dlyTicks` therefore becomes `false` after `dlyTicks` milliseconds (actually may be up-to 1ms less because `msTicks` is incremented asynchronously to any`Delay()` call).

Answer (score 0):

*SysTick* is the short name for *System Timer*. It's a timer generating a periodic interrupt. If the interrupt occurs, `SysTick_Handler` is called. In increases the variable `msTicks` by 1. Since the timer is configured to interrupt every millisecond (more about it later), `msTicks` represents the number of milliseconds since the microcontroller started.

`Delay` takes the current value of `msTicks` and loops (waits) until it has reached the initial value plus `dlyTicks`. The math in the function might look strange. But it's the proper way to do it overflow-safe.

`SysTick_Config` configures how frequently the system timer interrupt is trigger. This function takes the number of clock cycle as the period between interrupts. To make the period 1ms, the CPU core clock frequency (`CMU_ClockFreqGet(cmuClock_CORE)`) must be divided by 1000.

Comment: " But it's the proper way to do it overflow-safe" We can't tell since we don't know the type of `msTicks`. It might be signed, in which case the code might as well crash & burn.

Comment: I'm positive it's an unsigned type. Whoever wrote that code was aware of the overflow issues.

Comment: I wouldn't be so certain. A frightening amount of C programmers don't know the difference between overflow and wrap-around.